# How to make table width to be just large enough to fit its content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:text="" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:text="" />
    </TableRow>   
</TableLayout>
```

This is my xml. when I run the app, the second edit box just ignore its size and fill all width to reach screen boundary.
How can I fix editbox sizes in table row and center them
like this pic
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `stretch column` field. After using `*` instead of `1` will divide the views evenly. Do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:text="" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: In that case both editboxes are stretched, I want them to be exact square shape, like in the pic I have attached

Comment: @AramTadevosyan but your question heading says otherwise :). 
For achieving a square edittext you have to give width and height like you are already doing it.

Comment: sure the sizes is given, but unfortunately it is ignored and both inputs are stretched to boundaries of screen.

Comment: @AramTadevosyan it's due to the stretch column field. Use 4 or 6 instead of * then you will know the difference.